# tic tac toe not making changes in cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, tic-tac-toe

i linked my html with js and css but my code is not working. i tried using a class name for all the table cells but it still did not work
my html file:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="something.css">
<!--bootstrap library-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/4.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>tic tac toe</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-bg">
    <h1 class="display-4 text-color" style="font-weight: 500  ">WELCOME</h1>
    <p class="lead">play tic tac toe</p>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <p></p>
    <p class="lead">
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">start</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td ></td>
        <td ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td ></td>
        <td ></td>
        <td ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td ></td>
        <td ></td>
        <td ></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

<script src="tictac.js">

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

ignore start button
i linked this with js code for making changes above code worked correctly and printed a 3x3 table with empty cells with help of css

my js code:

```
var table = document.querySelectorAll('td')
function click(){
  if(this.textComment==""){
    this.textComment="o"
  }
  if (this.textComment=="o") {
    this.textComment=""
  }
  if (this.textComment=="") {
    this.textComment="x"

  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
  table[i].addEventListener("click", click())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On first glance I can see that you need to bind the function `click` and not it's execution result. Change your **event listener** line to `table[i].addEventListener("click", click)`.

Also I think you meant to use `textContent` and not `textComment` inside `click`.